# Updating Github repo already cloned on EC2 instance

Tags: git, amazon-ec2

Could somebody explain the proper terminal command to update a repo sitting on my Amazon EC2 machine? I've already done a git clone 'git url' and the repository is now on my EC2 instance, but I'd like to know how to update the repo.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you set up git with the proper remote, i.e. master, you can just use `git pull` or `git pull origin`.

You can read more about remotes here: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.

List current remotes with `git remote`, and add one with something like `git remote add linux-nfs git://linux-nfs.org/pub/linux/nfs-2.6.git`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update a cloned repo to the current state of the remote you cloned it from, you likely need [`git pull`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you need to do this:

```
git commit -a 
<This will take you into vim, hit the letter 'i' and begin typing your commit message. Then, Hit Esc, and type ':wq' and enter to save. 
git push
```

Good luck!